# Unable to download/upload App Engine data due to 'Illegal string "dev~None" in dataset id.'

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I receive the following error:

```
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: \
    Illegal string "dev~None" in dataset id.
```

When I try to use my production database in my local development environment:

```
$ appcfg.py download_data \
    --application=s~app-id \
    --url=http://app-id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api \
    --filename=database.ndb

$ appcfg.py upload_data \
    --application=dev~app-id \
    --url=http://localhost:53828/_ah/remote_api \
    --filename=database.ndb
```

Any tips?  My best guess is that something is broken by the transition from `appcfg.py` to `gcloud`. I use the latter most of the time, but I can't find a way to accomplish this task using `gcloud`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Were you able to figure out how to solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. My hypothesis remains something being broken by the transition from `appcfg.py` to `gcloud`. Hopefully the App Engine team can look into it. As a workaround, I wrote a script that populates my dev database with procedurally generated production-like data.

Answer (score 1):

When running local appengine you have to specify -A parameter to set any application ID, otherwise you will be getting `Illegal string "dev~None" in dataset id` error. Took me a while to figure this out. Old environment variable APPLICATION_ID doesn't work (and application id from yaml file is neither is taken).